# Building Tableview in Viewcontroller with custom number of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I Have a `ViewController` and I have added a `UITableview` in it, In `UITableview` I need to create 3 Rows and each row should perform different operations like,
1st cell have Disclosure Indicator which will take us to another `ViewController` and 2nd Cell have Switch button when it is made on it should take us to some other `ViewController` and 3rd Cell some other operation,

Problem here is I made everything but can't able to view the output when I run the Project am getting the blank page!

I have checked Starting point and all other stuffs!

What may be the problem?

Comment: your view controller is loaded or not, or uitableviiew not loaded

Comment: see if u missed the tableview outlet connections and its delegate connection. As you didn't post the code you need to debug it urself.See if your methods get hit if u place breakpoints in them.

Comment: view controller and tableview is also loaded and am getting blank ! no information in the screen

Comment: Post your code so we can take a look! :D

Comment: Lots of things can lead you to a blank screen: are you using static or dynamic cells? If dynamic, is your datasource correctly setup (either in code or in Interface Builder)? If you are using AutoLayout, are your constraints setup correctly to show your UITableView? You can also search for "Static Cells tutorials" on the interwebs and follow something like: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/